# What is the value of $x$ in this equation

Tags: logarithms

I want to find the value of $x$ in this equation, by using logarithms.

$ \ 18^{4x-3} = (54 \sqrt{2})^{3x-4}  \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$18=(3\sqrt2)^2$$  and $$(3\sqrt2)^3=?$$

So, take logarithm in both sides with respect to base $3\sqrt2$

Comment: It's 54√2 ! Got it!

Comment: Can you tell me how it came up in your mind that the base should be 3√2 ?

Comment: @RaviPrakash, $$\sqrt{18}=?$$

Comment: Because both sides can be written by $3\sqrt2$ to the power of something

Comment: Thank you to both. And without log too we can simply equate powers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this way $$18^{4x-3}=3^{2(4x-3)}\times 2^{1(4x-3)}$$$$(54\sqrt2)^{3x-4}=3^{3(3x-4)}\times2^{\frac{3}{2}(3x-4)}$$and$$18^{4x-3}=(54\sqrt2)^{3x-4}$$so $$3^{2(4x-3)}\times 2^{1(4x-3)}=3^{3(3x-4)}\times2^{\frac{3}{2}(3x-4)}$$equating powers of $2$ or $3$ you get$$8x-6=9x-12$$$$x=6$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $ ((3\sqrt{2})^2)^{4x-3}=((3\sqrt{2})^3)^{3x-4}$

So that means $(3\sqrt{2})^{8x-6}=(3\sqrt{2})^{9x-12}$.

Taking the logarithm of both sides with respect to base $3\sqrt{2}$ gives us $8x-6=9x-12$, which means $x=6$.

Comment: How you reached the conclusion that the base should be 3√2 ?

Comment: We are able to rewrite the equation in terms of powers of $3\sqrt{2}$, so it logically follows to take the logarithm with respect to that base

Comment: Yes, or without log we can simply equate powers.

Comment: absolutely correct! i just chose to get rid of the powers @RaviPrakash